# Как Windows выбирает DNS-сервер и как сохранить резолв локальных ресурсов при использовании public dns?

Tags: windows, windows-10, dns, windows-server

Есть локальный домен и несколько ресурсов в нем (назовем их `a.local`, `b.local`, `c.local`).
При этом, у `a.local` и `b.local` так же есть внешние адреса, которые доступны из веба.

Моя машина тоже находится в локальном домене. У нее один сетевой интерфейс.
Я хочу, чтобы ресурсы, которые имеют внешний адрес (`a.local`, `b.local`), с моей машины резолвились по их внешним адресам. А те, которые доступны только локально (`c.local`), продолжали резолвиться по внутреннем адресам.

На первый взгляд человека, который не разбирается в том, как Windows ранжирует dns-сервера, решение есть - указать паблик днс (тот же `8.8.8.8`) как preferred dns и указать `внутренний dns` как alternate. Но практика показала, что это не работает на Server 2019 (теряется возможность вообще резолвить внутренние сервера и все запросы идут через `8.8.8.8`).
Хотя раньше, во времена 2008, в случае, если preferred не смог зарезолвить ресурс, запрос перенаправлялся на alternate ([пруф на docs.microsoft.com](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd197552(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) после слов "The DNS Client service queries the DNS servers in the following order").

**Как это работает сейчас?**

hosts трогать не хочу, тем более MS считает данный способ deprecated и с недавних пор дефендер ругается на любое изменение hosts. По некоторым причинам (политики ИБ), изменение конфигурации `внутреннего dns`-сервера тоже невозможно.

Comment: *Хотя раньше, во времена 2008, в случае, если preferred не смог зарезолвить ресурс, запрос перенаправлялся на alternate (пруф на docs.microsoft.com после слов "The DNS Client service queries the DNS servers in the following order").* В упор не вижу там перенаправления на alternate, если preferred ответил. Или Вы имеете в виду вовсе не то, о чём говорит статья - она говорит о перенаправлении на сервер из настроек другого интерфейса, т.е. о мультихоме, а это немного иное. У Вас же - один адаптер, и поведение не изменилось - если preferred не смог, но хоть как-то ответил, других не спрашивать.

Comment: @Akina пункт 3 разве не об этом? If the DNS Client service does not receive a response from any DNS server within two seconds, the DNS Client service sends the query to (!) all DNS servers on all adapters (!) that are still under consideration and waits another two seconds for a response. Конечно тут не сказано, что запрос улетит на alternate, но т.к. запрос отправится на all DNS servers on all adapters, на alternate он попадёт в том числе (и получит у него ответ, завершив цикл).

Comment: Я, конечно, могу что-то неправильно понимать. Впрочем, если это только о ситуации, когда доступно несколько интерфейсов, окей, можно проигнорировать последнюю часть.

Comment: В описании - мультихом. Всё. Эта информация к одноинтерфейсному компу неприменима.

Comment: @Akina Хорошо, понял

Comment: У Вас - если первый хоть что-то ответил (даже "не знаю"), то второй не опрашивается.